# ST_SnapToGrid units

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, geocoding, postgis

I'm working with a postgresql table that contains many rows with a `GEOMETRY(Point, 4326)`. Using the `ST_SnapToGrid` function and a `DISTINCT` select, I only extract a subset of rows depending on the displayed map zoom level. I'm having trouble finetuning the `ST_SnapToGrid` function, as I don't not what unit the `size` parameter is in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size is specified in the same units as the SRID of the geometry.
In the case of SRID 4326 this is decimal degrees.  The actual distance
that is of course varies depending on the actual latitude and longitude
of the point in question.  If this matters, if might help to work in
some projected coordinates and do the rounding there.

Comment: it's also possible to use `GEOGRAPHY` data type http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/geography.html in that case PostGIS will use a meters.

Comment: ST_SnapToGrid does not take `GEOGRAPHY` as parameter. Do you mean using something like `SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(180 90)', 4326), 0.00001)::geography;`  ?